# bash: Add all words double quotes

Tags: bash, sed

I hope to add double quotes of all words.

example, this sentense.

> abc,def,,jkl

I want conversion:

> "abc","def","","jkl"

Then, I try to conversion, it was failed.
How can I do it?

```
sed "s/[^ ][^ ]*/'&'/g"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enclose zero or more non-comma characters with double quotes:

```
sed 's/[^,]*/"&"/g' file
```

Comment: Thank you but, There is a problem that \ n is inserted in the last word.

Comment: The command outputs only matching strings and `"`. Do you mean a literal `\n`?

Comment: Yes It is. How can I do it?

Comment: Could you paste your output string here?

Comment: @ko_ma this command does not add any newline characters (I guess that's what you're referring to). You should edit your question to show how you are passing your string to sed, and also how you are printing the result. I guess that you are using `echo` at some point, which adds a newline.

Comment: @ko_ma you have CRs in your input. What you're seeing isn't `\n`s being added by the script its the `\r`s showing up within the double quotes of the last field. Run `dos2unix` or similar on your input file before running UNIX commands on it.